# How to increase mouse sensitivity?

Tags: release-loki, mouse

I'm using elementary OS 4.0.1. Below is the output of `xinput list-props <id>`. Acceleration speed is set on 1.0, but it is still slow. I tried to use `xset m 2 1`, but it gives nothing :(

```
Device 'Razer Razer Abyssus':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (274): 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (275): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (276):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (277):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (278):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (279):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (280):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (259): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (260):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (261):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (281): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (282): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (283):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (284):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (285):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (286): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (287): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (288):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (289):    0
    Device Node (262):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (263):    5426, 66
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (290):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (291):   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use xset m 20/2 10

With my touchpad it gives me just the right about of sensitivity. You might need to adjust to your liking.

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration) is a good source of info for mouse acceleration.

Comment: I'd tried it with different values, it gives no effect

Comment: I would input: "xset q | grep -A 1 Pointer" to view the current acceleration and threshold settings. Then input the acceleration as a fraction 2/1 or 20/2 as I have mine, while setting the acceleration as a whole number as you have it.

Comment: it have no effect immediately. I tried to reboot too. Yes, like this or with fraction:xset m 2/1 1, xset m 3/1 1.

Comment: what is the out put of xset q | grep -A 1 Pointer?

Comment: Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  2/1    threshold:  1.
These values are changing when im trying to set them. I also tried to put a different values from 2 to 10000 - no changes.